# How to run if statements based on two string variables?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert in a range a word based on two string variables searched in another range.

Something like:
If abc is found in range A to last row, then insert in range B to last row the word good, if not also insert the word good.

And if in the same range A to last row is found xyz string, then skip the part which inserts the word good, and run the part that inserts word bad, not the word good.

I have tried something like this but, I don't know hot to skip the first part if the second string is found.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
For Each Cell In rng.Cells
    If InStr(1, Cell, "vf7") > 0 Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "CIT"
    ElseIf InStr(1, Cell, "VF7") > 0 Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "CIT"
    Else
        Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "CIT"
    End If
Next
    
For Each Cell In rng.Cells
    If InStr(1, Cell, "vf3") > 0 Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "PGT"
    ElseIf InStr(1, Cell, "VF3") > 0 Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "PGT"
    Else
        Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "PGT"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Please tag with programming language.

Comment: Since you are not calling subs at all, the title of your question doesn't match your question. In any event, if you only want to execute a block of code conditionally, wrap it in `If ... Then .... End If`

Comment: @ John Coleman  this a part of a bigger macro